# MeteorJS and alethes:pages

Tags: javascript, meteor, pagination

I am trying to build simple MeteorJS application that uses iron-route and alethes:pages package for pagination.

I am defining my route:

***lib/routes.js***

```
Router.route('/test' {
});
```

***lib/collections/testCollection.js***

```
Test = new Mongo.Collection("test");
```

***server/publications.js***

```
Pages = new Meteor.Pagination(Test);
```

In my template:

***client/test.html***

```
<template name="test">

{{> pages}}

</template>
```

Nothing is showing ? Can someone help me see the problem? 
(Database is populated: _id "field" and test "field" in document structure.)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, then tried to change the names such that my template name matched the collection name and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

The

```
Pages = new Meteor.Pagination(Test);
```

it can't be on a server side code only. It has to be in a common code, running on both the server and the client